# Converting python objects for rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

The following code is supposed to create a heatmap in rpy2

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects import r
data = np.random.random((10,10))
r.heatmap(data)
```

However, it results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z.py", line 8, in <module>
    labRow=rowNames, labCol=colNames)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 418, in __call__
    new_args = [conversion.py2ri(a) for a in args]
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 93, in default_py2ri
    raise(ValueError("Nothing can be done for the type %s at the moment." %(type(o))))
ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <type 'numpy.ndarray'> at the moment.
```

From the documentation I learn that r.heatmap expects "a numeric matrix". How do I convert np.array to the required data type?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to add

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
```

See more in rpy2 documentation [numpy section](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/numpy.html) ([here](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/numpy.html) for the older 2.x version)

Prior to 2.2.x the import alone was sufficient.

> That import alone is sufficient to
>   switch an automatic conversion of
>   numpy objects into rpy2 objects.
>
> Why make this an optional import,
>   while it could have been included in
>   the function py2ri() (as done in the
>   original patch submitted for that
>   function) ?
>
> Although both are valid and reasonable
>   options, the design decision was taken
>   in order to decouple rpy2 from numpy
>   the most, and do not assume that
>   having numpy installed automatically
>   meant that a programmer wanted to use
>   it.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of how to "explicitly activate" the conversion as mentioned in the edit @lgautier. I am encountering a similar problem that worked in an older version of rpy2 but seems broken in rpy2 2.2.2. Can you provide a brief example?

Comment: For future readers: add `rpy2.robjects.activate()` after the import. They had problems with the import having side-effects.

Answer (score 11):

For rpy2 2.2.4 I had to add:

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
```

Answer (score 2):

For me (2.2.1) the following also worked (as documented on http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/numpy.html):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri
ro.conversion.py2ri = numpy2ri
```