# Dynamic Time Warping in Python

Tags: python

Does anyone know of a python library that has DTW implementation? [mlpy](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/) seems to have what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to install it correctly -- currently awaiting replies from the mailing list so I thought I would scope out other libraries.

Comment: ldd /bin/delorean     libplutonium.1.21.so => /lib/libplutonium.1.21.so

Comment: People assume that time is a strict progression of cause to effect, but *actually* - from a non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint - it's more like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey, er, stuff.

Comment: [Mr. Special Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity)

Comment: @C. Reed - it was a play on @flow's Dr. Who quote :P

Comment: I wrote a C extension to Python to do the central calculation in classic Dynamic Programming / Dynamic Time Warp. It runs typically 500x faster than a straight Python version. See the code and ipython notebook demonstration at https://github.com/dpwe/dp_python .

Comment: This lib may help you: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Comment: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397144/7109869) may be of help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the record, I have been able to use a mashup of [R](http://www.r-project.org/), [DTW in R](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org/), and [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html). Working with R in Python is surprisingly simple and extends python's statistical capabilities considerably. Here's an example of finding the distance between an offset noisy sine and cosine series:

```
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    r = robjects.r
    r('library("dtw")')
    idx = r.seq(0,6.28,len=100)
    template = r.cos(idx)
    query = r.sin(idx)+r('runif(100)/10')
    alignment=r.dtw(query,template,keep=r('TRUE'))
    robjects.globalenv["alignment"] =  alignment
    dist = r('alignment$distance')
    print(dist)
```

---

Comment: Just a note from the future: this question is now superseded by the [feature-equivalent `dtw-python` package](https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/python/) (also found [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/dtw-python/)). The rpy2-R-dtw bridge should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 24):

Had to chime in on this one. To follow up with C's response, here's an implementation that is geared more towards interfacing with data generated in NumPy. I find this to be considerably more useful since typically I'm generating data in Python and want to interface with R resources.

```
import numpy as np

import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

# Set up our R namespaces
R = rpy2.robjects.r
DTW = importr('dtw')

# Generate our data
idx = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
template = np.cos(idx)
query = np.sin(idx) + np.array(R.runif(100))/10

# Calculate the alignment vector and corresponding distance
alignment = R.dtw(query, template, keep=True)
dist = alignment.rx('distance')[0][0]

print(dist)
```

Note that this is the example problem stated on the [DTW site](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks! One of the things I love about this approach is that it seems as though rpy2 plays smoothly with the multiprocessing module in Python. So if you have a lot of data that you want to process on a multicore machine, it's the way to go!

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant, I ran into this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447454/converting-python-objects-for-rpy2

Comment: How is this method compared with the Python mlpy.dtw package?>

Comment: Using R within python must be painfully slow.

Comment: Note that addition of this line is required by recent versions of rpy: `rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()`

Comment: @tonigi added the missing line

Comment: Questions: 1) from the docs it is not clear to me what the measurement unit is for `dist`. Is this the same unit as the original time series? 2) is `dist` the non-normalized, minimum global distance between the two series? If so, why is it minimum?