# Implement R package TSdist from python

Tags: python, r, time-series, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I'm trying to implement the R package [TSdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSdist/TSdist.pdf) from python jupyter notebook.

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

R = rpy2.robjects.r
## load in package 
TSdist = importr('TSdist')
## t,c are two series 
dist = TSdist.ERPDistance(t.values,c.values,g=0,sigma =30)
## dist is a R Boolean vector with one value
dist[0]
```

This gives me an NA and I got a warning:

> /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:186:
>   RRuntimeWarning: Error : The series must be univariate vectors
>
> warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)

Any ideas of how to properly implement it? Or how to measure time series similarity with python packages using discrete Fourier transforms (DFT), Auto-regressive coefficient, Edit distance on real sequence(EDR). Methods mentioned in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3973.pdf) paper.

Comment: The error is likely *before* `dist[0]`, when calling `ERPDistance()`, and as the error message issued by the R code you are trying to run indicates it your input is invalid.

Comment: I've tried this implementation (`TSdist.ERPDistance(t.values,c.values,g=0,sigma =30)`) of the function in R studio and it works. And the implementation in python is referenced with this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695388/dynamic-time-warping-in-python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the reason is the two *series* objects being passed into the method. Assuming series mean *pandas series*, calling `values` returns a numpy array. And per the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSdist/TSdist.pdf), the `ERPDistance` expects numeric vectors, not arrays.

```
print(type(pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(pd.Series(np.random.randn(5)).values))
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Consider simply casting series as *numeric* vectors with base R or use rpy2's `FloatVector`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

R = rpy2.robjects.r
## load in package 
base = importr('base')
TSdist = importr('TSdist')

new_t = base.as_numeric(t.tolist())
print(type(new_t))
# <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>

new_c = rpy2.robjects.FloatVector(c.tolist())
print(type(new_c))
# <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>

## new_t, new_c are now numeric vectors
dist = TSdist.ERPDistance(new_t, new_c, g=0, sigma =30)
```