# 'ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <class 'numpy.core.records.recarray'> at the moment' error

Tags: python, r, numpy, rpy2

I am trying to run a simple linear regression (using rpy2 from Python) and encountered a strangely worded error when running the script below:

```
from numpy import array, rec
from numpy.random import normal as nprandom
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri, r

foo = array(range(10))
bar = foo + nprandom(0,1,10)

d = rec.fromarrays([foo, bar], names=('foo','bar'))
fit = r.lm('bar ~ foo', data=d)
print fit.rx2('coefficients')
```

here is the console output:

```
>>> from numpy import array, rec
>>> from numpy.random import normal as nprandom
>>> from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri, r
>>> 
>>> foo = array(range(10))
>>> bar = foo + nprandom(0,1,10)
>>> 
>>> d = rec.fromarrays([foo, bar], names=('foo','bar'))
>>> fit = r.lm('bar ~ foo', data=d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 33, in __call__
    new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 134, in default_py2ri
    raise(ValueError("Nothing can be done for the type %s at the moment." %(type(o))))
ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <class 'numpy.core.records.recarray'> at the moment.
>>> print fit.rx2('coefficients')
```

I am running Python 2.6.5 and have numpy version 1.6.1

Does any one know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
rpy2.robjects.activate()
```

after importing `numpy2ri`. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447454/converting-python-objects-for-rpy2) references the rpy2 documentation:

> That import alone is sufficient to switch an automatic conversion of
>   numpy objects into rpy2 objects.
>
> Why make this an optional import, while it could have been included in
>   the function py2ri() (as done in the original patch submitted for that
>   function) ?
>
> Although both are valid and reasonable options, the design decision
>   was taken in order to decouple rpy2 from numpy the most, and do not
>   assume that having numpy installed automatically meant that a
>   programmer wanted to use it.

Hope this solves your problem.