# Creating R matrix from Numpy Matrix

Tags: python, r, rpy2

How would I go about creating an R matrix from a numpy matrix using rpy2? 
I've tried `robjects.r.matrix([the numpy matrix])` but it doesn't work with a np matrix (or array).

Comment: I think this question addresses yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447454/converting-python-objects-for-rpy2